# Recursive query very slow in Postgres 12

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

I have this recursive SQL query that looks roughly like this

```
with recursive recCTE as (
  select parent,name from items 
  where id in (...) 
  union 
  select items.parent, items.name 
  from items 
  join recCTE on recCTE.parent=items.id
)
select * from recCTE
```

`id` is the primary key of the `items` table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items ( 
      id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
      parent bigint REFERENCES items(id) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
      name text NOT NULL,  
    );
```

The in clause can either be a list of values or a select on a temporary table (no significant performance difference between the two cases).
The performance is pretty bad, as in it takes one second for an input list of a thousand numbers. We are going up a tree, so each pass on the recursive query should yield less and less results.

Execution plans show a Recursive union using a nested loop on the non recursive query and a Hash join on the recursive part, with a seq scan on the items table. I've run analyze on the table.

```
CTE Scan on reccte  (cost=283046.17..286189.29 rows=157156 width=144) (actual time=43.233..1644.449 rows=1091 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=26532 read=23328, local hit=14, temp read=3880 written=9664
  CTE reccte
    ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.42..283046.17 rows=157156 width=71) (actual time=43.230..1644.078 rows=1091 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared hit=26532 read=23328, local hit=14, temp read=3880 written=9664
          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..11202.20 rows=1556 width=71) (actual time=43.224..45.111 rows=1000 loops=1)
                Buffers: shared hit=4000, local hit=14
                ->  Seq Scan on temp1817829968_0  (cost=0.00..29.56 rows=1556 width=8) (actual time=0.111..0.216 rows=1000 loops=1)
                      Buffers: local hit=14
                ->  Index Scan using items_pkey on items  (cost=0.42..7.18 rows=1 width=71) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1000)
                      Index Cond: (id = temp1817829968_0.value)
                      Buffers: shared hit=4000
          ->  Hash Join  (cost=22587.04..26870.08 rows=15560 width=71) (actual time=350.280..399.117 rows=272 loops=4)
                Hash Cond: (reccte_1.parent = items_1.id)
                Buffers: shared hit=22532 read=23328, temp read=3880 written=9664
                ->  WorkTable Scan on reccte reccte_1  (cost=0.00..311.20 rows=15560 width=8) (actual time=0.567..0.604 rows=273 loops=4)
                ->  Hash  (cost=14715.24..14715.24 rows=325024 width=71) (actual time=341.619..341.619 rows=325024 loops=4)
                      Buckets: 65536  Batches: 16  Memory Usage: 2035kB
                      Buffers: shared hit=22532 read=23328, temp written=9580
                      ->  Seq Scan on items items_1  (cost=0.00..14715.24 rows=325024 width=71) (actual time=0.010..170.582 rows=325024 loops=4)
                            Buffers: shared hit=22532 read=23328
Planning Time: 0.384 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 17
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 14.542 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 2.713 ms, Emission 41.963 ms, Total 59.218 ms
Execution Time: 1666.414 ms
```

Is the JIT a problem?

I rewrote the client JDBC code to not use a recursive query, to just do `select parent,name from items where id in (...)` and recursively capture the parent ids and rerun the query. This performs a hundred times faster (tens of milliseconds instead of a second).

I find hard to believe that the optimizer could not basically do the same thing that I do in my code, so what's wrong with this type of query? Is the fact that we going up a tree and getting duplicate `parent` value the problem? Any advice?

Thanks a million!

Comment: The plan is not made up, it's a copy paste of pgadmin output

Comment: Your query takes 63 milliseconds (0.063 seconds) - that hardly seems "very slow". Also: the Seq Scan on the `items_1` table is never executed

Comment: Added another plan with better values in the temp table

Comment: `parent integer REFERENCES items(id)` <<-- do you have a FK like this , plus its supporting index ?

Comment: @wildplasser, there is a foreign key and an index, but the column is nullable

Comment: Of course it is NULLable. Please add the relevant DDL to your question. Maybe also some of the config parameters.

Comment: @wildplasser Added DDL. I just pass -c max_locks_per_transaction=256 -c max_connections=400 to the docker container (running 12.2)